# Azure DevOps pipeline - runtime parameters - pull list of docker images from ACR, and show as a dropdown parameter in Run Pipeline page

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, runtime

Azure DevOps pipeline

I'd like to have a list of docker images published to my project, as a runtime parameters

So one can go to "Run Pipeline" page, and select a value from the dropdown list - the pipeline should pull that list from ACR dynamically...

[image]
[image]

In other words - I'd like to promote an image from Dev to Prod - without going to the ACR itself to retrieve the list of available images...

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-DevOps-pipeline---runtime-paramete/10389491